# Can't change Android CalendarView to another month (Samsung S Duos - Android 4.2.2)

Tags: android, calendarview

Android introduced a CalendarView back in in API 11. I've implemented it in my app and it seems to work fine in the sense that it displays a perfectly normal-looking whole-month calendar and I can select a date. It triggers the appropriate event and I can read the selected date in my code with no problem.

[image: screen shot of my CalendarView]

**But** I can't advance it out of the current month!   The documentation says

> A user can select a date by taping on it and can scroll and fling the
>   calendar to a desired date.

(the "taping" appears in the documentation; I assume it's a typo for "tapping" )

I've tried flinging, swiping, scrolling and nothing happens.  Is there something I need to do to enable this feature?

My XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- This linear layout is because the scrollview can have only 1 direct child -->
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!-- Relative layout for Workorder -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rellayWorkorder"
            android:background="#383838"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/workorderlabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Work Order:"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/workorderContent"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="---workorder---"/>
        </RelativeLayout>


        <!-- Relative layout for Required Time
   <FrameLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"></FrameLayout> -->

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rellayRequiredTime"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/requiredTimelabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Required Time:"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/requiredTimeContent"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="--- 00 minutes ---"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- Relative layout for Time remaining -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rellayTimeRemaining"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/timeremaininglabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Time Remaining:"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tviewtimeremainingContent"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="--- 0:00:00---"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <!--  Linear layout for Record Start / Record End buttons -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"  >
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/debulkrecordStart"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:onClick="OnSetRecordStartTimeClick"
                android:text="Record Start"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/debulkrecordEnd"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:onClick="OnSetRecordEndTimeClick"
                android:text="Record End"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Relative layout for Vacuum level -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rellayvacuumlevel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/vaclabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Vacuum Level (inches Hg):"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/vacleveledit"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight = "true"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:inputType="text|textCapCharacters"
                android:text="vac level"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- Relative layout for Vac Gauge Equipment # -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlayvacuumGauge"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/vacgaugelabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Vac Gauge Equipment #:"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/vacgaugeedit"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight = "true"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:inputType="text|textCapCharacters"
                android:text="equip. #"/>
        </RelativeLayout>



        <!-- Relative layout for Calibration Due date -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlaycalibdue"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/calibduelabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Calibration Due Date:"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/calibdueedit"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight = "true"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:inputType="text|textCapCharacters"
                android:text="mm/dd/yyyy"/>
        </RelativeLayout>


        <CalendarView
            android:id="@+id/debulkcalendar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="240dp"
            android:minDate="01/01/2016"
            android:maxDate="11/30/2016"
            />


        <!--  this linear layout is for the debulk override and done buttons  -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"  >
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/debulkOverride"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:onClick="OnResetClick"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Override"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/debulkDone"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:onClick="onDoneBtnClick"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Done"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**Edits:**
Sorry for the long XML - in my original posting I just had the CalendarView but someone requested the entire XML.

Also to rule out the possibility that it might be unique to the device I've tested this on my Samsung S5 (Android 5.0) and got the same results.

Comment: @Artur Gniewowski  - no that has nothing to do with it.  That question is about generating and processing events in the code-behind  My question is about about the behavior of the UI.

Comment: Is it specific to (Samsung S Duos - Android 4.2.2)? Did you try on other devices?

Comment: Can you post the whole XML layout?

Comment: @mgcaguioa   Yes, I also tried it on an S5 running Android 5.0 and got the same results.  (Edited my post to reflect this)    Also, I took your suggestion and posted the whole XML - I didn't do that originally because, as you can see, it's huge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as per my assumption, it's not scrolling or fling just because of a scrollable parent, can you check it without scroll view?

because I tested it with

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/debulkcalendar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="240dp"
    android:minDate="01/01/2016"
    android:maxDate="11/30/2016"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and its work perfectly

you can use [NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html)

> NestedScrollView is just like ScrollView, but it supports acting as
>   both a nested scrolling parent and child on both new and old versions
>   of Android. Nested scrolling is enabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

@RBK was right, your parentView(`ScrollView`) interferes with its childView(`CalendarView`) which makes your `CalendarView` unscrollable. However, you can create your custom `CalendarView` which extends the base `CalendarView` class and override `onInterceptTouchEvent` method to get what you want.

Create your custom CalendarView class:

```
public class CalendarViewScrollable extends CalendarView {

    public CalendarViewScrollable(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CalendarViewScrollable(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CalendarViewScrollable(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                              int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (ev.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            ViewParent p = getParent();
            if (p != null)
                p.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Use it in your XML layout file:

```
<com.example.app.views.CalendarViewScrollable
 android:id="@+id/debulkcalendar"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="240dp"
 android:minDate="01/01/2016"
 android:maxDate="11/30/2016" />
```

Reference from this [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21989019/3955965)

Comment: I think it's better to use the inbuilt class like NestedScrollView instead of customizing any class.