# android - scroll input - date picker inside scroll view

Tags: android, dialog

I have the following layout for a dialog (I need to get user's birthday information) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Where were you born ?"
    android:id="@+id/textView_BirthPlace"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="13dp"
    android:textColor="@color/heading_text_color"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="What time were you born ?"
    android:id="@+id/textView_BirthTime"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="13dp"
    android:textColor="@color/heading_text_color"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"/>

<TimePicker
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/timePicker"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="When were you born ?"
    android:id="@+id/textView_BirthDate"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="13dp"
    android:textColor="@color/heading_text_color"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"/>

<DatePicker
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/datePicker"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

It looks as follows :

[image]

The problem is when the user has to pick a date from the date picker, the scroll input sometimes goes to the enclosing scroll view (I have scroll view as the linear layout proves too long for the screen size I am testing on).

How can I make sure that when user scrolls over date picker that the entire layout doesn't scroll ?

Comment: I had the same problem, unfortunately I had to use a DatePickerDialog and it works without any problem. [Good example](http://pulse7.net/android/date-picker-dialog-time-picker-dialog-android/) and [another example](http://androidopentutorials.com/android-datepickerdialog-on-edittext-click-event/)

Answer (score 0):

I just extended the DatePicker class and override the onInterceptTouchEvent as one member here shared.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9687545

```
public class CustomDatePicker extends DatePicker {


        public CustomDatePicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
        {
            if (ev.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                ViewParent p = getParent();
                if (p != null)
                    p.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Then you just use it like this:

```
<pt.example.appYoumade.CustomDatePicker
           android:id="@+id/docEnd_datePicker"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:calendarViewShown="false"/>
```