# Android 5.0 Datepicker in scrollview not working (not scrolling months)

Tags: android, datepicker, android-scrollview

I have the new datepicker implemented in an fragment. This is wrapped in a scrollview. When trying to use the datepicker i have to click and hold somewhere on the screen before i can scroll through the datepickers calader to let's say may.

is there a way to fix this?

im using this timepicker:
[image]

And im loading it like this:

```
 <ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
    android:layout_row="11"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:background="#162229"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#162229"

    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="#162229"
        android:calendarTextColor="#fff"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:calendarViewShown="false" > <!-- style="@style/date_picker_style" -->
    </DatePicker>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I had the same problem, unfortunately I had to use a DatePickerDialog and it works without any problem. [Good example](http://pulse7.net/android/date-picker-dialog-time-picker-dialog-android/) and [another example](http://androidopentutorials.com/android-datepickerdialog-on-edittext-click-event/)

Comment: i too had the same issue. That time i used  **bold'android:datePickerMode="spinner"' ** to avoid the issue. But the look and feel will not get

Comment: My best guess is that the scrollview parent is trapping the gestures and they need to be handled by the DatePicker before the ScrollView gets them.  I'm afraid I may wind up just going with the DatePickerDialog option as well.

Answer (score 16):

Create a class that extends DatePicker and override the following method:

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
{
    if (ev.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        ViewParent p = getParent();
        if (p != null)
            p.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    }

    return false;
}
```

It'll work fine. 
source : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9687545/2178259)

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the parent ScrollView component. Either remove the scroll view or use date picker dialog.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was useful:
[How to disable and enable the scrolling on android ScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893198/how-to-disable-and-enable-the-scrolling-on-android-scrollview)

Custom scroll view that you lock when appropriate