# LinearLayout not correctly resizing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have a LinearLayout and dynamically add three LinearLayouts to it. Each of the LinearLayouts contains a Button. After pressing one of the Buttons I wanted to display a CalendarView in the second-level LinearLayout. The View is displayed, however, it is not shown fully. I have attached a screenshot to visualize the problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE9je.png

Here is the code for adding the layout:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams pLayouts = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
);
hllCalendar = new LinearLayout(this);
hllCalendar.setLayoutParams(pLayouts);
hllCalendar.setId(hllCalendarID);
hllCalendar.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
btCalendar = {some other code}
hllCalendar.addView(btCalendar);
hllComponents.addView(hllCalendar);
```

And here is the code for adding the CalendarView:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams pCalendar = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
);
CalendarView cal = new CalendarView(this);
cal.setLayoutParams(pCalendar);
cal.setOnDateChangeListener(this);
hllCalendar.addView(cal);
```

Any suggestions on how I could make the calendar fully visible?

Here is the dynamically created layout for your convenience:

```
hllComponents pLayouts
-hllCalendar pLayouts
--btCalendar
--CalendarView pCalendar
-hllStartTime pLayouts
--btStartTime
-hllEndTime pLayouts
--btEndTime
```

---

The problem is the same as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894732/android-calendarview-timepicker-not-working-inside-scrollview).

Comment: You would need to add the LayoutParams you set onto the neighboring linear layouts

Comment: @ZedScio The LayoutParams for Layouts is pLayouts as you can see in the first code section.

Comment: I meant the layouts surrounding hllCalendar. The most likely culprit is that hllCalendar does not have enough room to resize to wrap_content. You can test this by putting hllCalendar inside a scrollview. If you can scroll through and see the entire view, then the issue is the layouts above and/or below hllCalendar, inside hllComponents.

Comment: @ZedScio I have added a hierarchy to my original post for you to see my current layout. Even if I remove the second and third LinearLayout the CalendarView is still not expanded, even with Udinic's help.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the requestLayout() of the parent layout.

This will post a "relayout" message on the UI's messages loop. This will calculate the new size of the layout, after the calendar was added, and thus paint it fully on the screen.

Comment: Unfortunatly that did not work out. I added these lines to the second snippet:
`hllCalendar.addView(cal);hllCalendar.requestLayout();
   hllComponents.requestLayout();`